# How to use babel presets in react-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-rails

I have a rails app using the react-rails gem, and I'd like to use arrow functions and static function declaration:

```
class Component {
  static propTypes = { ... }

  onClick = (e) => { ... }
}
```

I tried adding an initializer but I don't know how to add the `stage-3` preset from babel:

```
// stage-3 not found
config.react.jsx_transform_options = {
  optional: ["stage-3"]
}

// preset option doesn't exist
config.react.jsx_transform_options = {
  preset: ["stage-3"]
}
```

How can I use babel presets with react-rails?

Comment: Can you use the `.babelrc`? Our babel config goes in there but we're using webpacker + react-rails instead of sprockets.